# how deserialize string pattern to object

Tags: c#, object, serialization

I receive from tcpstream message with this format :

["bilbo,1,0,0,0,0,1,2022-11-21 19:06:10","mangnoune,1,0,0,0,0,2,2022-11-21 19:08:18"]

["string, int, int, float, float, float, int, DateTime","next array pattern"]

I want to deserialize this to:

```
class player
{
  string name;
  int level;
  int xp;
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  int status;
  Datetime lastPlayed;
}
```

In this example there are 2 players objects.

Comment: Wasn't it flagged as PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy option is to use [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-6.0) first to obtain a list of player strings and then parse each string individually.

I am using an extension method here which allows to [deconstruct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct#user-defined-types) an array with 8 values, but that's not necessary, you can just as well use the array indices directly.

From that point onward it's just about converting `string` to `int` which you can do using the [`Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=net-6.0) class and about parsing a Date which you can do using [`DateTime.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-6.0).

> This implementation will throw exceptions for unexpected data.

```cs
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Program
{
    record Player(string Name, int Level, int Xp, float X, float Y, float Z, int Status, DateTime LastPlayed);

    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"[""bilbo,1,0,0,0,0,1,2022-11-21 19:06:10"",""mangnoune,1,0,0,0,0,2,2022-11-21 19:08:18""]";
            var playerStrings = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<string>>(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)));

            var parsedPlayers = playerStrings
                .Select(playerString => ParsePlayer(playerString))
                .ToList();
            foreach (var player in parsedPlayers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(player);
            }
        }

        public static Player ParsePlayer(string playerString)
        {
            var (name, level, xp, x, y, z, status, lastPlayed) = playerString.Split(",");
            return new Player
            (
                Name: name,
                Level: Convert.ToInt32(level),
                Xp: Convert.ToInt32(xp),
                X: Convert.ToInt32(x),
                Y: Convert.ToInt32(y),
                Z: Convert.ToInt32(z),
                Status: Convert.ToInt32(status),
                LastPlayed: DateTime.Parse(lastPlayed)
            );
        }

    }

    static class ArrayExtensions
    {
        public static void Deconstruct<T>(this T[] srcArray, out T a0, out T a1, out T a2, out T a3, out T a4, out T a5, out T a6, out T a7)
        {
            if (srcArray == null || srcArray.Length < 8)
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(srcArray));

            a0 = srcArray[0];
            a1 = srcArray[1];
            a2 = srcArray[2];
            a3 = srcArray[3];
            a4 = srcArray[4];
            a5 = srcArray[5];
            a6 = srcArray[6];
            a7 = srcArray[7];
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
Player { Name = bilbo, Level = 1, Xp = 0, X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0, Status = 1, LastPlayed = 21/11/2022 19:06:10 }
Player { Name = mangnoune, Level = 1, Xp = 0, X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0, Status = 2, LastPlayed = 21/11/2022 19:08:18 }
```